# Jobs falling behind in Ultimate Cron, but none take very long to run

Tags: 8, cron

I have a total of 15 cron jobs set up in Ultimate Cron. 14 of them are set to run every 15 minutes, and 15th runs once a week. The longest of the 14 takes 22 seconds to complete.

They are only running twice a day, not every 15 minutes, and the Cron area always (correctly) reports them as behind schedule.

I tried changing them to run at set minutes per hour and increasing the number of threads to use for cron, but this didn't fix anything. Due to the cron tasks taking less than a minute to complete, I don't suspect this is because of the tasks interfering with each other.

I am pretty sure that this is because in the "Run cron" tab, under Cron Settings, "Run cron every" is set to 12 hours. I'd like to change this interval, but the most frequent option is 1 hour.

What am I missing here? I don't understand what the point is of having the option to run something every 15 minutes if the most often it can actually run is every hour. I don't think this setup is correct, and am not sure how to change it so that my cron jobs actually do run every 15 minutes.

Comment: have you setup  real CRON on your server to trigger Drupal's?

Comment: `I don't understand what the point is of having the option to run something every 15 minutes if the most often it can actually run is every hour.` Sounds like something is up here. Does this behavior also occur on a fresh install?

Comment: The setting "Run cron every" is for the so called *poor mans cron*, if you don't have access to a cron table. Because this runs at the end of user requests it is not advisable for larger sites. Outside of Drupal you can of course schedule shorter times, in a crontab for example down to a minute.

Comment: Thanks @4k4, I understand now. I'll need to set up a crontab wget for my site's cron launcher URL and disable the "Run every..." setting.